# Sqlalchemy/marshmallow single Code table join

Tags: sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I am implementing flask rest API with existing database. The db contain one common look up table, where multiple look up is separate by code categories.

```
Id = Primary Key , tablename = "CommonCode"

|id | code_category | codeValue | CodeDesc
------------------------------------------
|1  |  "season"     |    "1"    | "Summer"
|2  |  "season"     |    "2"    | "Winter"
|3  |  "status"     |     "1"   | "Success"
|4  |  "status"     |     "2"   | "Fail"
|5  |  "Deleted"    |    "Y"    | "Yes"
|6  |  "Deleted"    |     "N"   | "No"
```

I have many tables that referencing to the "CommonCode"

1. When I try too reference using the code below, it will  return the ID instead of the "Code Desc" column,
2. I am using marshmallow. If specifying the column, `ItemTypeDesc = field_for(CommonCode, 'CodeDesc')`
   the object will be return `"<Model.xxxx.CommonCode object at 0x00F8D710>`.
3. Is there recommended approach to implement common code table in sqlalchemy/marshmallow?

.

```
ItemType = db.Column(db.String(2),db.ForeignKey('CommonCode.codeValue'))

 ItemTypeDesc = db.relationship("CommonCode",
  primaryjoin="and_(Othertable.ItemType==CommonCode.codeValue, "
              "CommonCode.Code_Category=='season')",
  collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection('CodeDesc'))
```